# angular.js:13424 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'DemoCtrl123' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs

Hi I am just starting out with Angularjs have included following snippets in my index.html file(Django framework)  but it's giving me an error that controller is not a function. Kindly please help me fix this. I am using angular 1.5.3

```
index.html(Django framework) :
    <head>
    <script>
    app = angular.module('demoapp123', []);
    console.log("inside script....");
    app.controller('DemoCtrl123', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.num = "222";
        console.log("inside controller....");
    }]);
    </script>
    ..........
    </head>


    <body>
    {% verbatim %}
    <div ng-app="demoapp123">
    <div ng-controller="DemoCtrl123">
    <p>"Angular+controller"</p>
    <p>{{num}}</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    {% endverbatim %}
    </body>
```

Comment: Try putting the js code below the html (before the closing `</body>` tag)

Answer (score 0):

change the location of your script

index.html(Django framework) :

```
<head>

..........
</head>


<body>
{% verbatim %}
<div ng-app="demoapp123">
<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl123">
<p>"Angular+controller"</p>
<p>{{num}}</p>
</div>
</div>
{% endverbatim %}

<script>
app = angular.module('demoapp123', []);
console.log("inside script....");
app.controller('DemoCtrl123', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.num = "222";
    console.log("inside controller....");
}]);
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks , it was a beginners mistake. Got rectified.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry please dont waste your time on this one. Figured it out later. For reference of other newbie who may make similar mistake: apparently ng-app has to be unique  per html document. I was using 2 different ng-app hence the one I posted was not getting detected.